# Is it OK to have a very large documentView for an NSScrollView?

Tags: cocoa, size, document, nsscrollview

I have a really really long set of data I'd like to display in an NSScrollView.

Is there any way to specify a virtual documentView width of several billion pixels, but just render to clipView sized actual documentView?  Using a large documentView seems to work, but it doesn't seem like the right thing to do.

I'd use a plain ol'NSView, but I'd like to get the mouse/gesture scrolling capabilities for free.

Answer (score 3):

If you use a standard document view (an NSClipView), the only pixels that will render are those inside the contentSize of the scrollview it's assigned to. So if you set the scrollview's contentSize to be reasonably small, it should display fine no matter how large the bounds of the documentView.

If what you're worried about is loading a lot of data into memory, think about breaking the data into pieces. Each piece should be somewhat larger than what the scrollview's contentSize can display. Monitor the scrolling position so that, when it nears the edge of the content currently on display, you prepare to load the next piece.

Just to avoid confusion:

```
// How to determine the size of the area that will be displayed:
NSSize sizeOfDisplay = [scrollView contentSize]; 
// How to determine the full size of the content you have loaded:
NSRect rectFullContent = [[scrollView documentView] bounds];
NSSize sizeFullContent = rectFullContent.size;
```